# How do I uninstall Ruby on Rails and do a clean install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, rvm

I'm following a Rails tutorial. I'm having version problems with RVM and am getting lots of errors. I would like to start over with a clean version of Ruby, Rails, Gemfiles, etc.

Can anyone give me some brief instructions on how to uninstall my Ruby-on-Rails environment?

Comment: Which Rails tutorial? There are a bunch out there and many are badly out of date. The Rails Guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ are current so start there. Rather than blow things away I'd recommend starting with the last sentence in @Erick Herring's answer: "paste some of the error messages here and tell more about your operating system and configuration details". Start with `rvm info`. That can tell us some important things about what RVM knows about the PATH, Ruby and gems environments.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
rvm get head
rvm reset
rvm remove ... # take the output of rvm list and do rvm remove for each item in the list
rvm cleanup
rvm repair
rvm notes # make sure that you've got all the dependencies mentioned in the output from this command
rvm install ... # reinstall your rubies
```

This is likely overkill, but it should get you close to a known-good configuration. If it doesn't, try:

```
rvm implode
```

That will completely remove RVM and you can start over from scratch.

If none of this works or you are still confused, paste some of the error messages here and tell more about your operating system and configuration details.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for this. A few extra details for anyone following these directions.

Comment: Similar issue. I just `rvm reset` and `bundle install` and I've been able to get back on track. Maybe worth try that out before get into the entire process.