# The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.18.1 -

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am getting:

```
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 0.18.1 - 
Update Cocoapods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
```

How to checkout cocoapods?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To update CocoaPods you can run:

```
$ [sudo] gem update cocoapods
```

If you would like to try a pre-release version of CocoaPods you can run:

```
$ [sudo] gem update cocoapods --pre
```

from [here](http://docs.cocoapods.org/guides/installing_cocoapods.html)

Comment: Don't start troubleshooting after you have updated your cocoapods installation until you have restarted your terminal...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem and upgrading to cocoapods 0.18.1 is not an option for me (at the moment).

In my case I wanted to stick with cocoapods 0.16.4. So, I double checked to make sure I was not using version 0.18.1.

```
$ pod --version
0.16.4
```

If you need to: uninstall any new version of cocoapods (when prompted select which version of cocoapods you want to uninstall):

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

I then switch my local repository from the 'master' to the '0.16' tag. I will be downgrading to repo '0.16' because that is more inline with my version of cocoapods (0.16.4).

```
$ cd ~/.cocoapods/master/
$ git checkout 0.16
```

You should now be using repo '0.16' instead of the 'master'.

```
$ cd ~/.cocoapods/master && git branch
* 0.16
master
```

Finally, I had to clean up my XCode project workspace by completely re-installing my Pods.

```
$ cd to/your/project
$ rm -rf Pods/
$ rm Podfile.lock
$ pod install
```

Now, my cocoapod version matches my repo version. Note: You switched your local repository from the 'master'. You can always switch back to the 'master' repo using `git checkout master`.

Answer (score 3):

All the other answers didn't help here. I'm no ruby expert, but I think my problem was, that I had 2 Ruby versions installed:

- the one that comes with OS X
- and one I had installed with rvm (Ruby Version Manager).

When I updated the gems, the wrong gems got updated. The symptom was, that the after the update the command line told me cocoapods was version 0.20.2, but when I did `pod --version` I got 0.16.0 back.

I guess this could have been corrected with a symlink cleanup at the wright place, but I decided to get rid of the second Ruby installation instead. I found a way to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581776/how-do-i-uninstall-ruby-on-rails-and-do-a-clean-install) - the answer of Erick.

After that I updated the cocoapod gem with `sudo gem update --system`, the the cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Now the `pod install` worked :-)

I hope the above makes sense. Please edit, if I'm wrong.

Comment: I'm getting 0.16.0 even after `sudo gem update --system` and `sudo gem install cocoapods`. Have you any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try gem install cocoapods:1.1.1 --user-install
where replace 1.1.1 to your desired virsion