# Error when running pod install

Tags: cocoapods

When I run the `pod install` command, I am getting the following error:

```
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 -  (currently using 0.39.0)
Update Cocoapods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
```

Updating is not an option for me currently.

I looked at [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16511705/2792531) but none of the solutions seemed to work for me.

How can I continue to use CocoaPods 0.39.0 for my dependency management?

Comment: What is the issue with updating the cocoapods?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cocoapods had an issue with rate limiting back in March and implemented sharding to avoid this problem in the future. There's a blog post [here](http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/) about it.

To fix this, you can either update to a 1.x version of Cocoapods or add the new source to the top of your Podfile:

```
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs"
```

You probably will need to **replace** the other source line.

---

If you continue having issues, it's likely because a specific pod does not have a spec accessible in the source you're now using. I ran into this issue with the [Apptentive SDK](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios). You can specify the source for an individual library in your Podfile likeso:

```
pod 'apptentive-ios', :git => 'https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios.git', :tag => 'v3.0.0'
```

Simply update `:git` and `:tag` with the correct values.

For a Github project, it may be easiest to go through the [Releases](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios/releases) page of whatever library you're looking at to find the tag you want for a specific version.

Comment: could u answer step wise step what to do in terminal

Answer (score 4):

At first In Podfile replace source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs" with "source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs"

Move to your workspace root folder by below command :

```
cd <path to your workspace>

Pod install
```

If it doesn't work well then try above steps after following below steps.

In Terminal follow these steps :

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
```

You see output similar to this:

```
cocoapods (0.27.1, 0.20.2)
cocoapods-core (0.27.1, 0.20.2)
cocoapods-downloader (0.2.0, 0.1.2)
```

now for a safer side delete all local pods using below command :

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-core
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods-downloader
```

safer side delete cocoa pods version 0.39.0

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods -v 0.39.0
```

reinstall cocoa pods version 0.39.0

```
sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.39.0
```

Then run below commands in terminal :

```
cd <path to your workspace>
pod install (this time it would fail again, but that's fine)
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git
cd specs
git checkout v0.32.1
```

Move to your workspace root folder by below command :

```
cd <path to your workspace>
```

run below commands :

```
rm -rf Pods
rm -rf Podfile.lock
pod install (this time you should be able to see it working)
```

Answer (score 4):

Write following command in terminal

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Comment: This command installs the latest version of CocoaPods. It doesn't make sense, the OP says "Updating is not an option for me currently"

Answer (score 1):

Hi I tried above all answers, But nothing got working, Finally I tried these Steps in Terminal.

```
1- Open Terminal
2- cd < Your Project File Location>
3- sudo gem install cocoapods --pre
4- pod setup
5- touch podfile
6- pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
```

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.

**If this error Occur**

**Add this below Code in your podfile**

post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
end
end
end

**[Then Also Change Deployment Target to 9.0 in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s6Re.png)**

(Your Project) > ios > Flutter > Flutter.podsec

And Finally it worked