# how to call 'pod setup' with cocoapods 0.39

Tags: cocoapods

I am using cocoapods 0.39 and i am getting a '1.0 required' error.

```
[!] The `master` repo requires CocoaPods 1.0.0 -  (currently using 0.39.0)
Update Cocoapods, or checkout the appropriate tag in the repo.
```

[Error when running pod install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557449/error-when-running-pod-install) explains how to make `pod install` command work, but I can't figure out how to succesfully pass `pod setup` as it seems to have the new repo build-in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to run `pod setup` with 0.39 call this instead:
`(cd ~/.cocoapods/repos && git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git && mv Specs master && cd master && git checkout v0.32.1)`

for making `pod install` follow my link in the original post or look at Mereuta's answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is some info about what happened.
http://blog.cocoapods.org/Sharding/

Just replace the current source in your Podfile with this:

https://github.com/CocoaPods/Old-Specs

Then run `pod install.`

Answer (score 2):

you can just execute this commande :

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: I have the same question as this thread and have run install .  I get an error though. Fetching: xcodeproj-1.4.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/xcodeproj

Answer (score 1):

For others who are facing the same problem, write following command in terminal

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```